# Take <a> tag value and set as cookie

Tags: javascript, php, html

So say we have an a tag in the page

```
<a href="www.url1.com">url1</a>
```

How can I set my cookie to `www.url1.com` with `javascript` `onclick`?

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with? That's what SO would be for. A Google search and a tutorial are probably what you need.

Comment: I dont know how to locate the tag and activate a function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804219/set-a-cookie-based-on-url-parameter

This isn't an answer to your question directly, but it's a good starting point to develop your script

Comment: A tutorial is definitely what you need, such as this [JavaScript DOM Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). And this [JavaScript Cookies Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: close aaron, but the src is onclick

Answer (score 0):

Say the `id` of your `<a>` tag is `myUrl`, then you can get the `href` value by

```
var myUrl = document.getElementById('myUrl').getAttribute("href");
```

You can set the cookie using

```
document.cookie = "href=" + myUrl;
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/quttmdx5/

Comment: yeah I'm looking for something a little more dynamic. Can we use this in javascript?

Comment: I didn't get you. What you mean by _dynamic_ ? And this is javascript